# response body from http get request using request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on express js and using the request package for http methods

```
request({
url:'http://custom-url',
method:'GET'},function(err,response,body){

console.log("Got Response : "+respnose.statusCode);
console.log("Body : "+body);
console.log("name is "+body.name);

})


My output is :
Got Response : 200
Body :{"name":"John","id":"139321"}
name is undefined
```

The body has a name parameter but i don't understand why body.name is undefined, please help !

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes the response comes in `String`.

Try to parse it in `JSON` object then use it

```
request({
  url: 'http://custom-url',
  method: 'GET'
}, function(err, response, body) {

  if (body && typeof body == "string") {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
  }

  console.log("Got Response : " + respnose.statusCode);
  console.log("Body : " + body);
  console.log("name is " + body.name);

})
```